# Pattern that doesn't match invalid dates like 20999-11-11 and 2009-01-111

Tags: java, regex, date

File `daty.txt` contains various dates, some of them are correct, other ones aren't. My current pattern looks like `\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}`. Unfortunately this matches invalid dates like `20999-11-11` and `2009-01-111`.

I need a pattern which will match valid dates, and not match the invalid ones.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fname = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/daty.txt";
        List<String> list = Dates(fname,"\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}");
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }

    public static List<String> Dates(String file, String pattern) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(file));
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                while (m.find()) {
                    String date = m.group();
                    try {
                        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        df.setLenient(false);
                        df.parse(date);
                        result.add(date);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say it doesn't remove dates you put in the title, are you talking about correct or incorrectly formatted dates?

Comment: the dates i put in the title need to be removed from the list where I keep the correctly parseable dates

Comment: Why not just don't parse the dates into the list with incorrect formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind and lookahead to say "only match if it's not preceded by a digit" and "only match if it's not followed by a digit":

```
"(?<!\\d)\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}(?!\\d)"
```

Here `(?<!\d)` means "not preceded by a digit" and `(?!\d)` means "not followed by a digit".

More detailed explanation: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also use word boundaries:

```
\\b\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\b
```

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: i've tried this one before, unfortunately with this pattern 2 dates are missing but thanks for the answer